# Form lost Polish characters

Tags: java, mysql, spring, character-encoding, thymeleaf

I lost my mind trying to add Polish characters like "ą, ę, ć, ł" etc. to my MySQL database. Steps I have done :

1. Set up "Method comparing inscription" to `utf8_unicode_ci`in my MySQL database.
2. Set up for all `varchar` fields `Method comparing inscription` to `utf8_unicode_ci`
3. In `application.properties` set :

```
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.mandatory-file-encoding=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
spring.http.encoding.force=true
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.content-type=text/html
spring.datasource.sqlScriptEncoding=UTF-8
```

4. To be sure in all HTML files add in `<head></head>` brackets `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>`
5. Set the configuration file like this:

```java
@Configuration
public class Config extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        filter.setForceEncoding(true);
    }
}
```

When I try to add some Polish words in my controller, for example `player.setName("ĆŁĘ")`- it's OK. The name in the database is correctly inserted.

But when I take the `name` of player in controller from Thymeleaf, it returns `ÄÅÄ` instead of `CŁĘ`. My form attendant Thymeleaf looks like this:

```xml
<form action="#" th:action="@{/editPlayer}" th:object="${player}" method="post">
    <div class="info">Name:</div>
    <div class="error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}"/>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" placeholder="Name" th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}? 'error'"/><br/>

    <input type="button" id="cancel" class="button2 button-cancel" value="CANCEL"/>
    <input type="submit" class="button button-submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
</form>
```

I have no idea what else I need to do to get correct characters from Thymeleaf.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, your question doesn't look that bad as you think it is. If the Downvoter could explain why he gave this question a -1 after just getting +2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution. It take me some steps:

1. Add annotation `@EnableWebSecurity` to my `Config` class,
2. Write `http.addFilterBefore(filter, CsrfFilter.class)` under `filter.setForceEncoding(true)`
3. Create class `ApplicationSecurityInitializer`

```
public class ApplicationSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
        super.beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(servletContext);
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic characterEncodingFilter;
        characterEncodingFilter = servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter",
                new CharacterEncodingFilter());
        characterEncodingFilter.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        characterEncodingFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
    }
}
```

4. Take a breath and be calm :)